# How to perform the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin(x) }{x }$?

Tags: integration

Does anybody know how  to perform the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin(x) }{x }
$$
Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to use $\LaTeX$.  Also, be sure to show some thoughts for the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thank you. Current, my only idea is to Taylor expand the $\sin(x)/x$ and collect terms, but I'm very sure there are some better ideas. For example, if some body knows the integral representation of $\sin(x)/x$, it may be a useful method.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208250/integral-of-sinc-function-multiplied-by-gaussian

Comment: I give my own answer to this problem. $1/x=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}dt$, and write $\sin(x)$ using Euler formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider :
$$f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}\sin(ax)}x\,dx$$
then 
\begin{align}
f'(a)&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{iax}\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-ia/2)^2-a^2/4}\,dx\\
&=e^{-a^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-ia/2)^2}\,dx\\
&=e^{-a^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy\quad(*)\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\;e^{-a^2/4}
\end{align}

($(*)$ a justification for this rewriting is provided in the comments)

Integrating again we get :

\begin{align}
f(a)&=\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^a\,e^{-a^2/4}\,da\\
f(a)&=\pi\;\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac a2\right)
\end{align}

(from the definition of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function))

and the answer will be  :
$$f(1)=\pi\;\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac 12\right)$$

Comment: I always think the parametrization trick is beautiful yet in a wicked way. +1.

Comment: Thanks @Shuhao ! I enjoy the more general formulas obtained this way.

Comment: @Raymond. So your answer shows me that not only integral representation, but also derivative representation is useful to perform integrals. Thank you.

Comment: Two remarks (other than this answer is incorrect).  The fifth equality in the derivation of $f'(a)$ is not a simple variable substitution but requires some argument involving contour integration.  Your "integrating again" step to obtain $f(a)$ misses an integration constant, which is in fact not zero.

Comment: @Wimc: If you mean the integration path parallel to the real line (of offset $-ia/2$) I knew that it didn't change the result (from playing with Fresnel integrals) but had not the time to insist on this. The $f(a)$ integration should be right since we are integrating $\operatorname{erf}$ that goes from $0$ to $a$ (with change of variable $t:=a/2$ so that the factor of $2$ disappears with the $2$ from erf definition). I had a missing factor of $2$ in the earlier part I think...

Comment: You are right.  Sorry for the noise. +1.

Comment: No problem @WimC and thanks.

Comment: @user86406: The point of WimC was that, to make the derivation more rigorous, one should write something like $$\int_{-R}^R e^{-(x-ia/2)^2}\,dx=\int_{-R-ia/2}^{R-ia/2}e^{-y^2}\,dy=\\\int_{-R-ia/2}^{-R} e^{-y^2}\,dy+\int_{-R}^R e^{-y^2}\,dy+\int_{R}^{R-ia/2} e^{-y^2}\,dy$$ Since $\,y\mapsto e^{-y^2}$ is an entire function (so that the integral is not path dependent) we may take the limit as $R\to\infty$ to eliminate the two supplementary integrals on both sides of $\displaystyle\int_{-R}^R e^{-y^2}\,dy$.

Comment: The method exposed here is what is named 'differentiating under the integral sign' and was popularized by [Richard Feynman](http://www.core.org.cn/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-304Spring-2006/80FAFE90-0273-499D-B3D6-EDECAFE3968D/0/integratnfeynman.pdf) see too Keith Conrad's [paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf).
You will notice that another non rigorous point in this derivation (as well as many others using this method) is that we should justify the exchange of the derivation and integration operations

Comment: (this is often done using uniform convergence and the existence and convergence of the different terms). I am fond of this method but Kirill's method is nice too!

Answer (score 9):

Write
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x} = \int_{-1}^1 \frac12 e^{i x y}\,dy, $$
so that the integral is
$$ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-1}^1\,dy \,e^{-x^2+i x y} = \frac12\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt\pi e^{-y^2/4}\,dy = \frac\pi2 \mathop{\text{erf}}(x/2)\Big|_{-1}^{1} = \pi \mathop{\text{erf}}(1/2). $$

Comment: I bet you of $2$ s Kirill ! :-)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni So you did, but I think you missed a factor of 2.

Comment: Gasp you are right thanks !