# Fourier transform of a Gaussian over a square window

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, fourier-transform

I am trying to evaluate an integral of the form
$$
G_T(\omega)
=
\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \mathrm{d}t ~ e^{-\sigma^2 t^2} e^{i\omega t}
$$
and I am looking for a closed-form expression. I know this integral can be rearranged into a convolution between a Gaussian and a sinc function, and an "incomplete" expression for that integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208250). I am however rather confused by the complex erf function in that answer, and I really need some clarifications.

Comment: If by complex you mean complicated: there is no closed form in terms (finite sums of) of elementary functions. The error function is essentially *defined* as the incomplete integral over a Gaussian, so you won't find a 'nicer' exact form than that. If by complex you mean $G\in \mathbb{C}$, then the result is purely real because only the real part of $e^{i\omega t}$ contributes to the integral over the symmetric domain $(-T/2,T/2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, after @Sal's  comment, you still need to be conviced that
$$G_T(\omega)=\int_{-\frac T2}^{+\frac T2} e^{-\sigma^2 t^2} e^{i\omega t}\,dt$$
$$G_T(\omega)=i\,\frac{ \sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sigma }\,e^{-\frac{\omega ^2}{4 \sigma ^2}}\left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\omega -i \sigma ^2 T}{2 \sigma
   }\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\omega +i \sigma ^2 T}{2 \sigma
   }\right)\right)$$ is not "intimidating", expand it as a Taylor series around $T=0$ and let $k=\frac{\omega ^2}{ \sigma ^2}$
$$G_T(\omega)=T\Bigg[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\, \frac{\sigma^{2n}}{4^n\,(2 n+1)!} a_n\,T^{2n}\Bigg]$$ The first $a_n$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 1 & k+2 \\
 2 & k^2+12 k+12 \\
 3 & k^3+30 k^2+180 k+120 \\
 4 & k^4+56 k^3+840 k^2+3360 k+1680 \\
 5 & k^5+90 k^4+2520 k^3+25200 k^2+75600 k+30240 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$